# Проблема с WP_Query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Скажите пожалуйста, в чем тут ошибка, мне нужна проверка по 2 полях для цены, но в таком варианте как на скрине не работает, страница не загружается, 2-3 мин загрузка, если брать что-то одно из тех что выделил, все нормально работает

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'erlond',
'posts_per_page' => '12',
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
 array( 'key' => 'item-type', 'value' =>  $apart_type, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
           'relation' => 'AND',
           array('key'       => 'item-main-price-field','value' => array(1, 400000),'type' => 'NUMERIC','compare' => 'BETWEEN',)
       ),
       array('relation' => 'AND',
           array('key' => 'main-price-in-dol','value' => array(4, 900000),'type' => 'NUMERIC','compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           )
       )
   ),
 array( 'key' => 'item-main-dist', 'value' =>  $apart_dist, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
 array( 'key' => 'item-main-rooms-count', 'value' =>  $apart_count, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
 array( 'key' => 'item-main-id', 'value' => $apart_id, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
 
)
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поставьте query-monitor. посмотрите какой запрос получается

Comment: Вы пишите запрос в БД, а не в инстаграмме сидите, чем меньше лайков, тем быстрее запрос)

Comment: Ваш запрос многократно просматривает всю таблицу `wp_post_meta`, сравнивая значения. А поле `meta_value` индекса не имеет. Вряд ли запрос можно оптимизировать средствами MySQL. Только кеширование в php.

Comment: меньше запросов никак не сделать, это фильтр поиска объектов недвижимости))
Проблему решил уже, надо было убрать ` 'relation' => 'AND' ` там где выделено на сирине, по другому получался цикл запросов, который работал по кругу и не выдавал результат, а query-monitor есть, но он этого не показал, получилось методом проб и ошибок))